# Depuis l'avion, de l'avion, en avion

Tags: grammaire, expressions

Je montre des photos des Alpes que j'avais prises lorsque j'étais dans l'avion depuis la fenêtre de l'avion.

Dans cette situation, comment devrais-je m'exprimer ?

- Voici les photos prises de l'avion
- Voici les photos prises depuis l'avion
- Voici les photos prises en avion

Laquelle parmi les trois propositions est la plus correcte et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je choisirais « Voici les photos prises **de** l'avion ». Elle est plus courte qu'avec *depuis* et ne présente aucune ambiguïté (*prises de l'avion* implique que l'appareil photo est dans l'avion), contrairement par exemple à « J'ai pris ces photos de l'avion » où l'on peut aussi comprendre *des photos où l'on peut voir l'avion*.

On utilise parfois ***depuis*** pour insister sur le fait qu'il ne s'agit pas d'une photo de l'avion lui-même mais cet usage est encore parfois controversé car il n'y a pas de mouvement lors de la prise d'une photo.

***Depuis*** n'avait originellement qu'un sens temporel mais s'est étendu à l'espace dans la mesure où un déplacement était effectué durant le temps correspondant. Si quelqu'un a dormi durant le vol d'un avion qui va de Paris à Marseille, on peut dire *il dort depuis Paris / il a dormi jusqu'à Marseille* car ces lieux correspondent à des moments précis, les instants où l'avion a décollé et où il a atterri. Quand on prend une photo, il n'y a pas de déplacement, c'est instantané donc la préposition peut être critiquée.  Voir par exemple cette page (prescriptiviste bien sûr) de [l'Académie](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/depuis).

***En** avion* est moins courant et moins précis que ***de***. Les photos ont bien été prises durant le vol mais elles montrent peut-être l'intérieur de l'avion alors que *prises de l'avion* implique que l'objectif était pointé vers l'extérieur.

Comment: Est-ce que le mouvement devrait avoir lieu ? Voici ce que dit Antidote : Le point de départ de l’action à distance considérée étant X. _Ils tiraient depuis les collines avoisinantes. Ils nous voyaient depuis le balcon du sixième étage._ Je ne comprends pas de quel mouvement tu parles.

Comment: Est-il possible d'employer "dès" aussi ? _Voici les photos prises **dès** l'avion_

Comment: @Oreste ***Dès** l'avion* est impossible car l'avion n'est ni une heure, ni le point de départ d'un déplacement. *Dès* introduit ce départ en insistant sur le fait qu'il est précoce *dès 5 heures du matin*, *dès le décollage*, ou, plus récemment, dans les publicités: *dès 10 €* pour *à partir de 10 €*.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de ***depuis***, Antidote est moins exigeant que l'Académie en acceptant *voir depuis le balcon du sixième étage*. Le mouvement qui manque est celui qui permettrait d'ajouter *jusqu'à* à cette phrase. En revanche, *ils tiraient depuis les collines* est conforme car on peut ajouter *jusqu'aux cibles*. Les projectiles sont bien en mouvement donc le sens originellement uniquement temporel de *depuis* peut s'appliquer à l'espace.

Answer (score 1):

« De » convient aussi bien que « depuis », ce de quoi  l'on peut s'assurer en consultant le TLFi, qui donne les deux comme synonymes l'un de l'autre (**IA2** ci-dessous).

[TLFi, depuis](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/depuis)

> **I.** − Prép. indiquant un point de référence initial, spatial ou temporel, à partir duquel une action se produit et dure, et spécifiant donc un intervalle dont le point terminal est éventuellement exprimé par jusqu'à/en/au.
> **A.** − [Dans l'espace]
> **2.** [**Empl. sans corrélatif, pour marquer la direction séparative**] Synon. de (v. de1), dès.
> **b)** [Sans mouvement]
> − [**Après des verbes d'énonciation comme dire, crier, s'écrier**]
> **Depuis le seuil, la porte, le perron**
> ♦ Elle se revoit, ce soir-là, assise dans sa chambre, devant la fenêtre ouverte (Bernard lui avait crié depuis le jardin : « N'allume pas à cause des moustiques »). Mauriac, Thérèse Desqueyroux,1927, p. 213.
> − **[Après des verbes de perception comme voir, apercevoir, entendre, distinguer]**
> ♦ Depuis la chambre, le pont, la coulisse.
> ♦ L'immense chaîne de montagnes qu'on embrasse depuis le pic.  (Maine de Biran, Journal,1816, p. 203)
> La place est pleine de boutiques. Vous pouvez en voir quelques-unes depuis la fenêtre
> ♦ Si peu qu'il fît de bruit, Mme Guillaume l'entendit, depuis la première pièce de la maison, où elle était couchée. Elle vit, sous la porte, un rais de lumière et demanda : − Cela ne va pas, Gilbert? Je viens, mon ami, je viens. Voulez-vous un linge chaud, une tisane? Arland, Ordre,1929p. 511.

([TLFi, de](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de))

> **I.** − De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
> **A.** − De exprime le point de départ.
> **2.** Le point de départ se situe dans l'espace.
> **e)** [De marque la direction séparative, la situation, le point de vue où l'on se place]
> − De marque la direction séparative, la situation, le point de vue où l'on se place pour faire quelque chose.
> [En parlant d'une action autre qu'un mouvement]
> ♦ Des fenêtres du premier étage, les policiers assiégés lançaient des grenades. (Malraux, Cond. hum.,1933, p. 248)

On peut dependant avoir une préférence pour « depuis », qui, étant une préposition peu surchargée de sens variés, à la différence de « de », peut sembler être moins sujet à équivoque.